# XSLT namespace-alias Not Working in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: xslt, cross-browser, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I am transforming xhtml to xhtml, but need an xslt stylesheet to be part of  the resulting document (the stylesheet will be contained in a `<script type"text/template">` element. I  am using the the `xsl:namespace-alias` instruction, which works fine in IE, but fails in both Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<xsl:output  doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="html" media-type="application/xhml" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="wxsl" result-prefix="xsl" />

  <xsl:template match="head">
     <!-- Some code omitted for clarity -->
       <script type="text/template">

        <wxsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:eli="local">

          <wxsl:template select="/">
            <wxsl:apply-templates />
        </wxsl:template>


      </wxsl:stylesheet>


    </script>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

It outputs the desired transformation in IE, but the XSLT processors for Firefox and Chrome are not replacing the `wxsl` prefix with `xsl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mozilla does not support it, there is an open bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213996 for that.

As for Chrome, I wrote a short test case with the XHTML input being http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016012402.xml (just a short XHTML sample with a `head` to add some XSLT then with XSLT) and the stylesheet http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016012401.xsl doing XHTML to XHTML transformation, using an alias to protect any XSLT and XSLT nested XHTML result elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:axsl="http://example.com/xsl-alias"
  xmlns:axhtml="http://example.com/xhtml-alias"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml axsl axhtml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axhtml" result-prefix="#default"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:head">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <axsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
      <axsl:template match="/">
        <axhtml:p>XSLT created paragraph.</axhtml:p>
      </axsl:template>
    </axsl:stylesheet>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And Chrome seems to transform that just fine, the console on inspection shows that the result elements are in the right namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<axsl:stylesheet xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"><axsl:template match="/"><axhtml:p xmlns:axhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">XSLT created paragraph.</axhtml:p></axsl:template></axsl:stylesheet></head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I have extended the test case to try to execute the embedded stylesheet and both Edge and Chrome are able to do that, see http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016012407.xml, although Chrome for reasons I have not been able to identify fails to do it in the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener I have set up. But that does not seem to be a problem related to using XSLT to insert XSLT, when I use the button to run the script doing the XSLT with the embedded stylesheet, it works fine in Chrome. Firefox obviously, with a lack of support for the `xsl:namespace-alias`, never finds the stylesheet root element to be able to have some code to feed to `XSLTProcessor`.